# evaluate the limit using L'Hospitals rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (\csc x - \frac 1x)$$

i have tried using the L'Hopitals rule on it in 3 successive derivations and haven't been able to come to a solid conclusion. the denominator just keeps getting longer and harder to differentiate while the numerator keeps switching between sinx and cosx. i believe there might be a simpler answer but unfortunately i can't seem to be able to get there.

Comment: This is just $$\frac{x-\sin{(x)}}{x\sin{(x)}}\sim \frac{x^3/6}{x^2}\to0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step should be to find a common denominator:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin{x}}{x\sin{x}}$$
Then apply L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos{x}}{\sin{x}+x\cos{x}}$$
Apply L'Hospital's rule again:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}+\cos{x}-x\sin{x}}=0$$

Comment: There's quite a jump between your last line and the $=0$ assertion. I think OP is looking for a bit more of a detailed solution.

Comment: @K.defaoite How is that "quite a jump"?  Plug in $x \to 0$.

Comment: Oops, computation error on my part. Thanks and nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without L'Hospital's rule as follows
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin{x}}{x\sin{x}}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\ldots\right)}{x\sin{x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^2}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{5!}+\ldots}{\sin{x}}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x}{3!}-\frac{x^3}{5!}+\ldots\right)\cdot \frac{x}{\sin{x}}$$
$$=0\times 1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital's rule is not tha alpha and omega of limits computation.

It is very simple using Taylor's formula at order $3$ for the sine:
\begin{align}
\csc x-\frac1x&=\frac1{\sin x}-x=\frac1{x-\cfrac{x^3}6+o(x^3)}-\frac1x=\frac 1x\biggl(\frac 1{1-\frac{x^2}6+o(x^2)}-1\biggr) \\
&=\frac1x\Bigl(\not1+\frac{x^2}6+o(x^2)-\not1\Bigr)=\frac x6+o(x)\to 0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{\sin x}$ has a simple pole with residue $1$ at the origin, hence the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}$ is finite.
On the other hand $\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}$ is an odd function, hence the limit has to be zero.